# I want to load html page in my div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

```
 function secondCategory(i) {
      var liName = 's_li_' + i;
      $('#' + liName).click(function() {
        $('.article').load('http://google.com');
      });
    }
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I like to load html page in my div tag, article.
but It occur an error 
**"Failed to load 'website adress': Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."**

```
[http://wedontknow.dothome.co.kr
./index.html
http://google.com][1]
```

above sites which I had tried occur the error.
how can I load html pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a server-sided issue. I've avoided `.load();` solely because of the CORs issue it always brings up. I'd glaze over this: [Enable CORs](https://enable-cors.org/server.html)

My recommendation, however, is to put all of your html code as strings in a JS file. This isn't as elegant and can be messy, but it's fast and easy to move around thereafter.

```
var html = '<div id="div-id"><p>Hi there!</p></div>';

$('#target-div').html(html);
```

That's always how I do things, although you could start to get some ridiculously long strings. You could concatenate them like so so it's easier to read:

```
var html = 
'<div id="wrapper">' +
    '<div id="inner">' +
        '<p>Hello!</p>' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>';

$('#target-div').html(html);
```

Not the prettiest thing to look at, but I've written entire full-blown web apps like this, it never presents security issues (namely, CORs) and is blazing fast.

## Using this method with multiple servers

Assuming you have a say in what the other server's response will be, you could always do a good ole post request.

```
var postData = {
    optionalData: 1234
};

$.post('https://google.com', postData, function(res) {
    $('#target-div').html(res)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't load external website unless you own it cause you need to enable cross-origin resource sharing

For local file, this error is happening because you are just opening html documents directly from the browser. To fix this you will need to serve your code from a webserver and access it on localhost

Comment: then why can't I load html file which is in my local?

Comment: Do you running it on localhost or server, or you just open directly html file?

Comment: directly html file. I realized the problem was there. but I don't know how to load html file in localhost until now.